# Spyder won't import h5py, but iPython console will. Why is that?

Tags: python, spyder, h5py

I am trying to open a .h5 file that contains data I need to plot, and I want to do this with Spyder (on macOS Big Sur). I have installed h5py through pip and here is what happens:

If I open an iPython console in the terminal, and run `import h5py`
everything works well, and I can navigate my data.

On the other hand if I run `import h5py` in Spyder, I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_errors' from partially initialized module 'h5py' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py)
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of Apple delivering Macs with Python installed. They think they are doing you a favor. Instead, they just complicate your life (especially if you want to use Conda Python.) For reference, Apple recently announced they will stop doing this for new Macs. (yeah - small victories!)

As a result, you have 2 Python installations: 1 preinstalled on the system, and the other is your Conda install. So, you have to be sure you are in the Conda environment when installing packages and running Python.

Your issue is similar to another recent question. Diagnosis is similar: [Python "tables" module "Not Found", but PIP and Conda say it is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71739061/10462884) To get started, take a look at diagnosis tips in my answer to that question.