# Python "tables" module "Not Found", but PIP and Conda say it is installed

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, python-module, pytables

I'm getting two errors in tandem when trying to export a Pandas DataFrame to HDF5 on M1 Mac:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 126, in import_optional_dependency
> module = importlib.import_module(name)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tables'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/casey/Documents/PythonProjects/untitled folder/json_load_test.py", line 19, in <module>
> objects.to_hdf('/Users/casey/Documents/PythonProjects/untitled folder/final.h5', key='objects')
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2775, in to_hdf
> pytables.to_hdf(
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 311, in to_hdf
> with HDFStore(
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 572, in **init**
> tables = import_optional_dependency("tables")
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 129, in import_optional_dependency
> raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pytables'.  Use pip or conda to install pytables.

But when I try to install "tables" using PIP I get this message:

> Requirement already satisfied: tables in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.7.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.0 in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from tables) (1.19.5)
> Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from tables) (21.3)
> Requirement already satisfied: numexpr>=2.6.2 in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from tables) (2.8.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from packaging->tables) (3.0.4)

And when using Conda to install "pytables" I get this message:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: done
>
> All requested packages already installed.

I've been stuck at this brick wall for a while now and just can't figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Read error messages closely. You have 2 Python installations. They are different versions, and probably have different packages installed.
First message references `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10`.
Second message references `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9`.
(FYI, Macs come with Python installed -- this complicates your life.)

Solution is to be consistent. Either install Pandas in the 3.10 environment, OR run Python in the 3.9 environment.

Here are some techniques to verify which Python and package versions you are running:

```
# to get Python version:
import sys
print(sys.version)

# to get package version: 
import package
print(package.__version__)
# where package is pandas, tables, etc
```

Conda and pip will list your packages and versions:

```
conda list (or conda list package_name)
pip list
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be installed in version 3.10 as well. Here is what I am getting when I run pip3 install tables:

Requirement already satisfied: tables in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.7.0)

I also manually looked in the folder itself and the package is in there.

When I select which Python version in VS Code I am using 3.10.4

Comment: Unsnarling errors with parallel Python installations is tricky. Be sure everything references the same installation/environment (including `pip`). What do you get when you enter: `import pandas; print(pandas.__version__)`? And the same for `import tables; print(tables.__version__)`?

Comment: The pandas version I get is "1.4.1"
When I try to import tables I get and error message ending with...
"  Reason: tried: '/Applications/Python 3.10/IDLE.app/Contents/Frameworks/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.200.dylib' (no such file)"